# staleSessionInactivityTimeout and staleSessionForceLogout not working in zuuk:meteor-stale-session

Tags: session, meteor, cookies

I posted this question on the package's github (https://github.com/lindleycb/meteor-stale-session/issues/19) but thought it couldn't hurt asking here as well.

I currently have the following flags set in my app's .json file. Even with staleSessionInactivityTimeout set to ~30 days and staleSessionForceLogout set to false, I notice that about every couple of days I am automatically logged out. What's the logic behind that?

Note I am using Chrome 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit) with default cache settings. I also have multiple AWS instances running different versions of my app (all sharing the same user db). So switching between instances is seamless since I only have to login once.

Note: I do notice that after switching between instances that under Chrome at `Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Content Settings -> Cookies -> All cookies and site data -> <my_app> -> Local Storage` changes upon every instance switch.  Maybe that's related (e.g. session cookie)?

```
"public" : {
  "env" : "prd",
  "staleSessionInactivityTimeout" : 2628000000,
  "staleSessionHeartbeatInterval" : 180000,
  "staleSessionPurgeInterval" : 60000,
  "staleSessionActivityEvents" : "mousemove click keydown",
  "staleSessionForceLogout" : false
}
```

Thanks!